# Show that there exists a unique solution $x(t) \in C([0,1])$ using contraction mapping.

Tags: functional-analysis, contraction-mapping

> Consider the integral equation:
> \begin{align*}
>   x(t) - \lambda\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{t-s}x(s)ds = \Gamma(t),
>  \end{align*}
> where $\Gamma(t) \in C([0,1])$ is a given function, and $\lambda$ is a real number satisfying $|\lambda|<1$. Show that there exists a unique solution $x(t) \in C([0,1])$ to the integral equation.

My idea is that consider $(C([0,1]),\rho)$, where $\rho(x,y) = \max\limits_{a\leq t\leq b}|x(t)-y(t)|$, and for each $x \in C([0,1])$, define $g(x)(t) = \Gamma(t)+\lambda\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{t-s}x(s)ds$. I am able to prove that $g$ is self-mapping. Then I need to prove that $g$ is contraction mapping. For $x,y \in C([0,1])$,

$|g(x)-g(y)|(t) = \left|\lambda\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{t-s}(x(s)-y(s))ds\right|\leq |\lambda|\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{t-s}ds.\rho(x,y)< (-e^{t-1}+e^t)\rho(x,y).$

However, when I take the maximum, I noticed that $\max\limits_{0\leq t \leq 1} (-e^{t-1}+e^t) = e-1>1$, so that I cannot prove that this is contraction mapping. Can somebody please help me to fix this?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. It should be $|g(x)-g(y)|$

Comment: $|\lambda| <1$ is not enough. I don't think you can fix this.

Comment: Okay, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y(t)=e^{-t}x(t).$ The equation takes the form $$y(t)-\lambda \int\limits_0^1y(s)\,ds =e^{-t}\Gamma(t)\quad (*)$$ Now we can apply  the contraction mapping theorem for $|\lambda|<1$ to the operator $$(Ty)(t)=e^{-t}\Gamma(t)+\lambda \int\limits_0^1y(s)\,ds$$ where $y\in C[0,1].$

**Remark** The equation $(*)$ has a very special form
$$y(t)=\lambda\int\limits_0^1y(s)\,ds +f(t)\quad (**)$$
Hence the solution is equal $y(t)=c+f(t)$ for a constant $c.$ Substituting this in $(**)$ gives
$$c+f(t)=\lambda c +\int\limits_0^1f(t)\,dt+f(t)$$
Therefore
$$c={1\over 1-\lambda}\int\limits_0^1f(t)\,dt,\quad \lambda\neq 1$$
For $\lambda=1$ there is no solution if $\int\limits_0^1f(t)\,dt\neq 0.$ If $\int\limits_0^1f(t)\,dt= 0,$ the solutions are equal $c+f(t)$ for any constant $c.$

Comment: Of course in the OP problem $\int_0^1 f(t) dt$ is not zero.

Comment: @Ian Who knows ? In the OP problem $\Gamma(t)$ is an arbitrary continuous function. So the integral of $e^{-t}\Gamma(t)$ may vanish.  By the way  the notation $\Gamma(t)$ is misleading.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right, they used $\Gamma$ for a generic function, I thought they meant the Gamma function. That's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The equation indeed has  a unique solution for any $\lambda \neq 1$ and Contraction Mapping Theorem is not the right approach.

Pulling out $e^{t}$ from the integral we see that the equation gives $x(t)=\Gamma (t)+ce^{t}$ for some constant  $c$.  To evaluate $c$ multiply this equation by $e^{-t}$ and integrate. You will get $c=\frac 1 {1-\lambda} \int_0^{1}e^{-s}\Gamma (s) ds$. Thus, this is the only possible solution.
Now go back to the original equation and check that this is indeed a solution.

Comment: Your $T$ is actually my $g$.

Comment: You should not write $g(x)$. $x$ is an element of $C[0,1]$, not a number between $0$ and $1$.  @hxllearnmath

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your comment. I was misled by OP's typing  mistakes. I have completely revised my answer. I hope it is correct.